# Volatile Member Functions (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, volatile

Given the following class:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    int value() const {
      return value_;
    }

  private:
    volatile int value_;
};
```

Does the value() member function also have to be marked as volatile to avoid getting optimized away or is it okay as written? Thanks.

Comment: +1: Good question! I would suggest no, because the compiler already knows not to optimize away `value_`

Comment: I would agree with what Nick sayed. I think some guys already had this problem in the past and that it was decided not to optimize when dealing with it :p

Comment: I mention this only because you have "multithreading" tagged and a lot of folks get this confused -- volatile in C++ doesn't make operations on value_ atomic.  The way your question is worded, it sounds like you already understand that that :)

Comment: I've read some of the earlier questions/answers but I'm still not certain if this member function should be marked as volatile or not..?

Comment: Why would making the member function volatile affect the optimization?

Comment: The worry is if I have MyClass c; and then call c.value(); a couple times, the compiler might think c.value() will return the same value (even though it could have possibly changed..)

Comment: @Switch: how/why would the value change (without the compiler knowing)?

Comment: But making the function `volatile` doesn't change anything in this respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the value() member function also have to be marked as volatile to avoid getting optimized away or is it okay as written?

Marking the member function volatile will have no effect on whether it is optimized away or not.  It is fine as written.

> The worry is if I have MyClass c; and then call c.value(); a couple times, the compiler might think c.value() will return the same value (even though it could have possibly changed..)

It sounds like what you want is to learn about atomic variables.  Take a look at std::atomic.

If you really want to learn about volatile, read this paper: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf

Answer (score 7):

It is completely analogous to how `const` works.

If you have a `const` object, only member functions marked `const` are callable.

And so...

If you have a `volatile` object, only member functions marked `volatile` are callable.

As long as the object itself is not `volatile`, it makes no difference whether the function is.

However, do keep in mind that `volatile` has *nothing* to do with multithreading, and it will *not* help you write thread-safe code. It is the wrong tool for anything concurrency-related.

Comment: I think what leads to a lot of the confusion is that the `Win32` atomic APIs `InterlockedIncrement` et. al. require a `volatile` parameter.  Windows handling of the `volatile` keyword in general strays significantly from what the C++ standard guarantees.

Comment: They don't *require* volatile parameters, they *accept* volatile parameters.

Comment: @Chad: no, you've got it upside down, as I said, it works just like `const` does. If a function takes a `const` parameter, that does not mean it *requires* a `const` argument. It means it *accepts* a `const` argument. A non-const object can always be converted to a const one. And a non-volatile one can always be convered to a volatile one. But you can't go the other way. So if you have a `volatile` object, you can only call functions that accept a `volatile` parameter

Comment: See all the confusion ;)  I just meant that there is a lot of information on how Windows specifically handles `volatile` variables that leads to the multithreading confusion relating to them.

Comment: but the example you cited has *nothing* to do with what Windows does with `volatile`. You're right that one point of confusion does exist on Windows. MSVC implements `volatile` as a full memory barrier, making it somewhat useful for synchronization between threads, even though this is not required by the standard. But there is *nothing* special about `InterlockedIncrement`'s volatile parameter. That just means that the function accepts *both* volatile and non-volatile arguments, and has nothing to do with MSVC's handling of volatile

Answer (score 4):

> The worry is if I have MyClass c; and then call c.value(); a couple times, the compiler might think c.value() will return the same value (even though it could have possibly changed..)

In a separate compilation model, where the compiler does not see the internals of the function, it cannot assume that they will not have side effects ([*]), and thus cannot remove the different calls to the function. If the compiler is seeing the definition of the function and inlining the code, then it *sees* that the member is `volatile` and thus cannot optimize it away either.

[*] Some compilers (namely gcc) have special attributes that you can use to tell it that a function is *pure* (i.e. it has no side effects and the output depends only on the arguments provided) to enable multiple calls to a function to be optimized away, for example in this loop:

```
const char* lit = "Literal";
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < strlen(lit); ++i ) {
    sum += lit[i];
}
```

Because `strlen` is marked as pure in the library, the compiler will cache the value and transform the loop into:

```
const char* lit = "Literal";
int sum = 0;
int __len = strlen(lit);
for ( int i = 0; i < __len; ++i ) {
    sum += lit[i];
}
```

But the library **must tell** the compiler specifically that this can be done. Without the extra information in the shape of attributes, nothing can be assumed and the `strlen` function would have to be called in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer. It addresses the issue of being optimized away and why it cannot happen due to the volatile.

Answer (score 2):

> ### Constant and volatile member functions (C++ only)
>
> A member function declared with the const qualifier can be called for
> constant and nonconstant objects. A nonconstant member function can
> only be called for a nonconstant object. Similarly, a member function
> declared with the volatile qualifier can be called for volatile and
> nonvolatile objects. A nonvolatile member function can only be called
> for a nonvolatile object.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr028.htm

Comment: Unrelated: This addresses whether the member function should be `volatile` based on the premise that the instance of the class is `volatile` (or not). In the question, the enclosing object is not `volatile`, rather one of the members of the object is.